# Implement like button in power apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am trying to implement a like feature in Microsoft power apps. I am having an issue when pressing the like button I am receiving the error

```
The type of this argument "LikedBy" does not match the expected type "Record" found type "text" instead.
```

The code I am using is

```
Patch(
ProposalLikes,
Defaults(ProposalLikes),
{   
    ThemeID: ThisItem.ID,
    Liked: 1,
    LikedBy: User().Email
}
```

)

and my structure data list looks like [image]

does anyone know why I am receiving this error?

Comment: Is `ProposalLikes` literally the table or is it a collection? It's certainly very strange that it is expecting a record when text makes the most sense for this.

Comment: What is the type of the 'LikedBy' column in your list? And +1 on Nick's question above - what is the type of ProposalLikes? Based on the image, it looks like a SharePoint list, but it would be good to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `LikedBy` is a Person-type column in the Sharepoint list. If so, it is a *Record* data type whereas `User().Email` is a *Text* data type. It can be tempting to use `User()` to patch Person-type columns, but the schemas don't match.

**Person-type Column Schema (Sharepoint)**:

```
{         
  '@odata.type':"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
  Claims:"i:0#.f|membership|user@user.com",
  Department:"",
  DisplayName:"",
  Email:"",
  JobTitle:"",
  Picture:""
}
```

**To Patch a Person-type Column, Try this:**

```
Patch(
    ProposalLikes,
    Defaults(ProposalLikes),
    {   
        ThemeID: ThisItem.ID,
        Liked: 1,
        LikedBy: 
        {
          '@odata.type':"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
           Claims:"i:0#.f|membership|" & User().Email,
           Department:"",
           DisplayName:User().FullName,
           Email:User().Email,
           JobTitle:"",
           Picture:""
        }
    }
)
```